# Count number of clicks on picture box

Tags: c#

With each click on the picture box the number in the output label must decrement by one.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Ricardo! Please read over the [site tour page](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) for information on how to post to this site. As is, your question is extremely broad. Please post your [MCVE].

Comment: Welcome to SO! To start getting answers you will need to attempt this, post the code you try, and explain any problems you are having so that we may help you with said issues. Please see the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help in improving your question. Thanks!

Comment: sorry for vagueness. Let me try it again.

Answer (score 1):

You need an event handler for the clicking of the image, and an int to keep track of how many times it was clicked; here is some pseudocode to get you started:

```
int timesClicked = 42;

private void Img_Click(sender object, eventargs e)
{
    timesClicked--;
    UpdateLabel();
}

internal void UpdateLabel()
{
    label.Caption = timesClicked.ToString();
}
```

Comment: B. Clay Shannon, as you may have guessed I am just the beginner in the programming on C#. Thank you for such a fast response anyways. We have never used the internal void method.

Comment: No problem; don't mind the downvoters - they expect everyone that posts a question to already be a joureyman programmer, and forget that everybody must start somewhere.

Comment: yeah, thanks. I understand that

Comment: It appears to be "private" access modifier does also work in this instance. Thanks you so much, again

Comment: @B.ClayShannon The downvotes are not because we expect everyone to be a 'journeyman programmer', it's because OP has made no effort whatsoever, and has asked us to do their work for them. SO is not a coding service.